# Realm swift2 installation failed with message "No version of Xcode found that supports Swift 2.0"

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

[realm installation command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiyYr.png)
I followed process that documented in Realm Official site.

but this error occurred. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.0` means  to use the Swift 2.0 comipler to build the Realm. Swift 2.0 needs Xcode 7 or higher. Are you make sure version of Xcode that was installed in you environment? If you'd like to build Realm with Swift 1.x, you can specify version of Swift like that: `REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=1.2 sh build.sh build`. Or if you just use Realm(you don't need to build Realm), you can download pre-built binary from Realm official site.

Answer (score 0):

Run `swift --version` to see your swift version, then you can compile.

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
$ REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.1.1 sh build.sh build
```